# Permissions - list all readable files?

Tags: permissions

How would I list all files in a directory that all users (i.e. owner, group and other) can read?

Comment: Including subdirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -444
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Is there a way to do this via grep also?

Comment: @Jbob Not directly. It doesn't make much sense but instead you could grep the output of `ls -l`.